# Eclipse won't recognize third-party packages

Tags: eclipse, scala, package

This is probably a newbie question because I'm a newbie with Eclipse. I've got a file in my Eclipse Scala project that imports salat classes using `import com.novus.salat._`. Eclipse gives me errors: "object salat is not a member of package com.novus" and "object novus is not a member of package com".

The package com.novus.salat is in my "src" folder in Eclipse, so I don't understand why I get these errors.

[image: my Eclipse folder tree]

The com.novus.salat package is linked from a source code folder ([path]/com/novus/salat/) outside of my Eclipse project directory. I couldn't copy the com folder into my project because the folder "com" already exists for something else, plus I don't want to do that anyway because I want the salat source code to be easily updatable by updating the git submodule (since it was cloned from GitHub). Linking the files instead of copying should work, right? I'm having the same problem with other packages I'm trying to import. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should link to the folder above com, most likely `.../src/main/scala`.  Since you probably already have a `scala` source folder you can name the folder something like `scalat_scala`.

Linking to the source will work as long as those source files compile, which will be the case as long as you have the dependencies of those source files on the classpath of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the best way, but this worked:

1. Make the package hierarchy outside of Eclipse. So `mkdir com`, `cd com`, `mkdir novus`, `cd novus`, `mkdir scalat`.
2. Drag the "com" folder into Eclipse under "src".
3. Drag the class files into the "scalat" package in Eclipse, linking or copying.

Apparently, it cares about how you set up your package hierarchy.